# Generics with Wildcards (Map<? extends A, List<? extends B>>)

Tags: java, list, generics, dictionary

Consider the following code:

```
public interface A {};

public class AImpl implements A {};

public interface B {};

public class BImpl implements B {};

public interface Service{
  Map<? extends A, List<? extends B>> get();
}
```

Why does the following implementation of Service not compile?

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
  public Map<AImpl, List<BImpl>> get() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Compiler error:

> The return type is incompatible with `Service.get()`

But the following code compile:

```
public interface Service{
   List<? extents B> get();
}

public class ServiceImpl implements Service{
   public List<BImpl> get(){
       return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: What does the error say? (i think you want extends instead of implements in the last code snippet)

Comment: I assume `extent` should be `extends`? You're also missing some `>`s. Please copy/paste **actual code that you've tested in an IDE**. Also, include your compiler error. You've wasted a lot of people's time by not doing this.

Comment: *extent in `Map<? extent A, List<? extent B> get()`....it is `extends`, fix that first and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of the `Service#get()` method is specified as

```
Map<? extends A, List<? extends B>> get();
```

And you are trying to return a

```
Map<AImpl, List<BImpl>>
```

You can use covariant return types. And it seems like you thought this would be the case here. But the problem is that this covariance does not apply to the generic type parameters. Although `List<BImpl>` is a subtype of `List<? extends B>`, this does not mean that `Map<AImpl, List<BImpl>>` is a subtype of `Map<? extends A, List<? extends B>>`.

A structurally similar but simpler case is that `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>`.

You could change the return type in the `Service` interface to

```
Map<? extends A, ? extends List<? extends B>> get();
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Because `<? extends BaseType>` means "some unspecified sub-type BaseType", and `class Sub extends BaseType`, while sub-type of `BaseType`, is not it. Read [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html), in particular starting from [Wildcard Capture](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Wildcard%20Capture) section, for more details.

You should generify your code properly:

```
public interface Service<K extends A, V extends B> {
    Map<K, List<V>> get();
}

public class ServiceImpl implements Service<AImpl, BImpl> {
    @Override
    public Map<AImpl, List<BImpl>> get() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say that this is plainly wrong: `List<AImpl>` is a subtype of `List<? extends A>`, so the `A` is not the problem. The problem is one level deeper, namely in the `List` argument (see my answer). But I'm waiting with my downvote, because generics are complicated ;-)

Comment: Your example compiles too. The difference is whether you need generic `Service` interface (my example) or not (your example).

Comment: The intention was probably to not have type parameters for the `Service` interface (and they are not necessary, at least as far as it is possible to say this based on the initial code sketch...). In any case, the *reason* why it did not compile was not related to `A`.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceImpl cannot be an interface because your Implementation cannot be in an interface; Change it to a base base class and try it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you write?

```
Map<? extents A, List<? extents B> get();
```

java doesn't know anything about `extents`

At least use `extends`